# Understanding how nested for loop works

Tags: java, sorting, for-loop

I can't understand how nested for loop works. Just doing ascending order program please explain me step by step how it works

```
class Ascending {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int temp;
    int a[] = {20, 10, 80, 70};
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++) {
        if (a[i] > a[j]) {
          temp = a[i];
          a[i] = a[j];
          a[j] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("\n after:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
20
10
80
70
```

after:

```
10
20
70
80
```

Comment: could you please format your code, so we can read it faster/better?

Comment: *What* don't you understand about it? Unless you can describe some specific confusion, it is unlikely somebody will spend the time to describe "everything" about nested for loops, because chances are they'll waste time describing something you *do* understand.

Comment: Sorry For that not formatting order.am new to the java programming.

Comment: Please, explain what you don't understand, the only question is the title... What don't you understand, the logic, how the loops works, how a `for loop` works, ... ? See [ask]

Comment: I don't understand logic.how the loops works on this line for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++)

Comment: @vigneshwaran add this to the question ;) Well, you should learn the basics of Java then. This would be faster for you. The block of statement are not that hard to understand

Comment: @AxelH okay. I had learn basics of java already.still if i write this looping program I just got confusing.Can u share some best tutorial for understanding looping concept.

Comment: @vigneshwaran are you trying to implement bubble sort algorithm? because if yes, this is not a proper usage if you want to use the bubble sort algorithm

Comment: @vigneshwaran take a look at this, if you want to understand looping http://pasteboard.co/ZT3ZqwDh.png

Comment: Yes am trying bubble sort algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How nester loops are working.

Well this is quite simple, a for loop is define as follow :

`for(init;condition;increment)`

- init : is executed once at the beginning
- condition : check before every execute (like a while)
- increment : will be done after the code in the loop

Here, with one loop,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    // code 
}
```

This will be the same as

```
int i = 0;
while(i < 4){
    // code
    i++;
}
```

If you have nested loops, the idea is the same, the inner loop will need to execute as many time as the condition is true before the outer one can increment and check his condition again.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //loop A
    for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++) { //loop B
         // code
    }
}
```

loop A will start with `i = 0`, then loop B will start with `j = i = 0`.
The code will be execute until `j => 4` to exit loop B. There, loop A will execute the increment part, `i = 1`.

The condition is still true so the loop will execute his code, the loop B will start with `j = i = 1`.

And again ... until loop A's condition is false.